# SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1

Tags: java, odbc, dao

I am searching an access database for an item code and returning the item Object as shown in the code below. Any advise as to why I am getting this error will be appreciated. Thanks

```
public Item getIteminfo(String itemCode) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
     Statement myStatement = getConnection();
     Item item = null;
     String itemDescription;
     int itemPrice;
     String sql = "SELECT * FROM itemCatalog WHERE ItemCode = '"+itemCode+"'";
     ResultSet results = myStatement.executeQuery(sql);

     while (results.next()){
         itemDescription = results.getString("Item Description");
         itemPrice = results.getInt("Item Price");
         item = new Item(itemDescription, itemPrice);
     }
     closeConnection();
     return item;
 }
}
```

Here's the error details :

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6956)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7113)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(JdbcOdbc.java:3109)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:337)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:252)
    at checkoutsimulation.DAO.getIteminfo(DAO.java:49)
    at checkoutsimulation.ItemCatalog.getItemdetails(ItemCatalog.java:61)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely familiar with Java or ODBC but I do know that databases do not take kindly to column names with spaces.

Try wrapping the column names in brackets.

`itemDescription = results.getString("[Item Description]");`

Answer (score 1):

I was also faced same problem. finally solved
nothing that, please check the db field name ItemCode(WHERE ItemCode = '"+itemCode+"'")
with your database
such error occurs when field name mistake on your SQL....

Answer (score 1):

In This case you should use `PreparedStatement`

```
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(""SELECT * FROM itemCatalog WHERE ItemCode=?");
st.setString(1,itemcode);
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you reference a non existing field in the select part of the query.
eg a query like the following.

```
Select MisSpeltFieldName from tblStuff
```